# Access forbidden to my localhost and subfolders on Kubuntu, after install and set up Phalcon Frameworks

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, phalcon, permission-denied

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-phalcon-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

I followed these instructions, but at the end, when I tested it on my browser "403 Forbidden" message appeared!
All my folders and subfolders in /www/ was accessible before that and their permissions didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial the apache configuration is as follows:

`<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory`

If you change that to the following:

`<Directory "/var/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted 
</Directory>`

and apply the several `Order allow,deny` and `allow from all` afterwards (when things are working) you will get better results.

Since that tutorial the configuration of apache has changed.
This : `Require all granted` is new since the latest versions of apache

Answer (score 0):

Check SELinux and iptable. If you possible disable both, and try again.